# CLion edit standard project Templates

Tags: c, clion

Im programming in C-Lion IDE. And I cant find a solution to create a c-file with a standard template. I need it because I have to have a comment block generated on the beginning of the file. 
I need this by **creating a new project**, so I have to change the main file of the standard project template.

But I couldnt find any solutions for this. Just how to create a template for a new file.
I want to keep the standard template and just change the created main.c file.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/file-and-code-templates.html).

Comment: @YiFei That seems to be a dead link now. Do you know if it is now possible to create project templates?

Comment: @izhang05 The link is not dead. But it is for file templates not for project templates. I did not found any solution and by now i am not using CLion. Maybe write a script to generate projects?