# How do you save project as templates in CLion?

Tags: templates, intellij-idea, project, clion, project-template

There is a helpful feature in Intellij that allows you to [save a project as a template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/saving-project-as-template.html). In CLion, I can only see the options "Save as Live Template" and "Save File as Template" in the tools window. I have searched on YouTrack, but there doesn't seem to be a feature request for this. Is there a way to accomplish this in CLion and how would it be done if it's possible?

Comment: Looks like a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287261/clion-edit-standard-project-templates)